# Java Static typing

Tags: java, static-typing

I am new to learning Java and was explained that every variable needs to be declared. Why do I not need to do this in two steps?

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(console.readLine("How old are you? "));
console.printf("a: %d", a);
```

Comment: Can you explain some more? I'm not sure what you're confused about.

Comment: Why *would* you need to do this in two steps, in your mind? It's easier to explain if we know what made you think that in the first place.

Comment: The reason i thought this would need to be done in two steps is because of Static typing. The response of the console.readLine is not being declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to declare a variable, but when you do so, you must specify a type (or a super type of what is on the right hand side).

The return value of `console.readLine("How old are you? ")` is a String and printf can take that as a parameter, so there is no missing type information.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from writing it in one line, i.e.

```
console.printf("a: %d", Integer.parseInt(console.readLine("How old are you? ")));
```

This will work without any problem. Writing it in one line becomes a question of preference / readability and whether you want to do anything with the variable before you print it...

As to your comment, you can check in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readLine()) that `console.readLine()` returns `String`.